# ¿Como mostrar la paginación de una tabla en vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hola amigos quisiera que me pueda ayudar, lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla donde me piden mostrar los 500 primeros registros, en total son 57000 productos, por parte del backend esta en laravel, lo hago de esta forma:

```
public function getProductos()
    {
        $productos = Product::paginate(500);
        $productos = $productos->load('unidades');
        return  $productos;
}
```

Y de esa forma se logro optimizar la carga de la tabla, lo que pasa es que ahora no encuentro la forma de mostrar los demas productos, quisiera su ayuda, así es mi tabla:

```
                            <tr class="headt">
                                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                                <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                          
                            <tr v-for="(item,index) in productos" :key="index">
                                <td scope="row">{{ item.id }}</td>
                                <td><img :src="'../../web/'+ item.image" alt="" width="48" ></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="item.name">     
                                <td ><input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="item.description"> 
                            </tr>
```

Y este es mi metodo:

```
        getProductos(){
            this.destroyDatatable_4();
            axios.get(route('producto.get')).then( (response) =>{
                    this.productos = response.data;
                    this.initDatatableExport_4('Productos');
            });
        },
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste/investigaste algo al respecto?

Comment: Lo estoy intentando con "Laravel Vue Pagination" https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination, pero aún no logro resolverlo

Comment: Si te decides a hacerlo con un paquete de terceros, agrega en la pregunta como lo implementaste y con qué problemas te encontraste (nunca lo usé, pero el readme parece bastante claro). Si vas a hacer la paginación manualmente, lo mismo, agrega a la pregunta lo que intentaste/investigaste y los problemas que te encontraste. De esa manera tendrás más chances de obtener una respuesta.